# Customize "create" message on a simpleform button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, simple-form

I have a calendar and when i click on buttons, i book a specialist for the half day. It redirects to same page if the booking is correctly saved in the base. While it proceeds, the button briefly change with the message "create booking". I want to custom this message, specially because during the operation it explodes the whole calendar table (done with simple calendar).

There is nothing about in the .yml for simple form. Is this from ActiveRecord messages? The .yml from these gem don't have those kind of message.

[Screen shot of the brief message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu7Q0.jpg)

Comment: if I understood correctly that you want to change the button text when you redirect back to your page, using Ajax with Jquery will be helpful.

Comment: Sure. It can fix it. I just wanted where to find the text from the message on the button.